# Change Catalog Type in Oracle BI Publisher 12.2.1.0.0

Tags: bi-publisher, oracle-bi

In Oracle BI Publisher 12.2.1.0.0, I have to change the Catalog Type to "Oracle BI Publisher - File System" to enable the Guest Account. However, it's hardcoded and unchangeable. What should I do?

[image: This is the photo]

I tried to set up a new version (12.2.1.4.0), but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You choose this setting once when installing your instance of BIP. You can't change it afterwards. The point of this setting is to allow installations of stand-alone BIP with File System - the historical, outdated way - or as a more modern installation which follows the catalog approach of Oracle Analytics (ex OBIEE).

If you choose File System, then you are setting yourself on a path which was abandoned as the standard way of doing things already over 7-8 years back.

Why would you want to do this?